# Howto debug asp.net app with local source from github e.g. EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2017

Having a working asp.net app. Now trying to replace one of the official bundled asp.net components with local clone of project from github. E.g. `EntityFrameworkCore`

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore

Using Visual Studio 2017. The best found so far is this post, but refering to outdated method with `global.json` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015/

Haven't found any updates to the post, maybe an out-of-box solution exists in Visual Studio? Should this be handled through the `NuGet` package system? Any tip is welcome.

Comment: In VS2017, all .Net core packages are pack in Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget packages. So if you want to debug one of its dependencies, such EntityFrameworkCore, you need to uninstall entire Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package and then reference all related package projects, which is complicated. So I suggest you select the Microsoft Symbol Servers options to debug into the EF Core code.

Comment: @Jonas Bojesen, Could you debug your ASP.NET app now?

Comment: Try to adapt to the recommendation in this https://forums.asp.net/t/2129843.aspx?Howto+debug+asp+net+app+with+local+source+from+github+e+g+EntityFrameworkCore+cross+post+from+SO+ But the structure I got gives tons of CS0122 - "is inaccessible due to its protection level". Now I will try straight to reproduce the recommendation in the response step by step.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Now step-by-step followed https://forums.asp.net/t/2129843.aspx?Howto+debug+asp+net+app+with+local+source+from+github+e+g+EntityFrameworkCore+cross+post+from+SO+ but stil the  CS0122 - "is inaccessible due to its protection level" appears when the solution is cleaned and rebuild.

Comment: @Jonas Bojesen, but it was the compiler error, not the real debugging issue now. You need to find whether it was related to the specific class or constructor or others in your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0122

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks! The projects from github (Mvc, EntityFrameworkCore,...) builds straight out of the box in my env, Visual Studio 2017. Similar with a Visual Studio generated `ASP.NET Core Web Application` project, builds and runs out of the box. Hence I suspect project setup and NuGet package references, somehow get different scopes and generates the inaccessible class properties. Now I consider try to build from command line, like described in the github readmes. Then maybe replicate this with the Visual Studio env.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT The rebuilds in the command line, actually made project dependencies more clear to me. Keept the `netstandard2.0` for the `Mvc` package and now managed to debug direct into the source of `Mvc` project. Will verify this solution and if works ok, then update the answer.

Comment: This might help:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answer https://forums.asp.net/t/2129843.aspx?Howto+debug+asp+net+app+with+local+source+from+github+e+g+EntityFrameworkCore+cross+post+from+SO+

Most significant difference, no replacement of the strict api `netstandard2.0` with broad api `netcoreapp2.0`. This preserves possibility for verification with a command-line build of the cloned github project.

Step-by-step instruction for example with `Mvc`project from github, release 2.0.0

- Clone `Mvc`project form github https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc
- Select tag e.g. release 2.0.0 : `>git checkout rel/2.0.0`
- Create test project from Visual Studio `ASP.NET Core Web Application` . e.g. `MyWebAsp.Net`.
- Remove full bundled asp.net package. In Projects, Dependencies remove NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` contains direct `WebHost.cs` together with the bundled pakages. 
  Pick from asp.net github project `MetaPackages` the `WebHost.cs` in `rel/2.0.0` version https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs
  and add it to the `MyWebAsp.Net` project. (same location as e.g. `Startup.cs`)
- Add NuGet dev package sources (bullet 2 forums.asp.net answer).
   https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-tools/api/v3/index.json
   https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-master/api/v3/index.json
- Now there are missing some of the asp.net packages bundled in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, add them to Dependencies, NuGet e.g. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel -Version 2.0.0` Note
  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package shouldn't be added :-) it will be added as project.
- To the solution add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` project and subprojects missing for the assembly. (bullet 7 forums.asp.net answer).
- For the project e.g. `MyWebAsp.Net` add Dependencies, project reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` project.
- Now everything should be in place. Could be verified with `Solution clean`, `Solution rebuild`. Then place a breakpoint in e.g. get method to `ValuesController.cs`, spin the debugger. When halted at the breakpoint Call Stack should open the source from the local clonede github `Mvc`project.